# Is possible to add capture values to lambda when do DatabaseReference::RunTransaction?

Tags: android, c++, firebase, android-ndk, firebase-realtime-database

I work with Firebase Realtime Database and want do add value to my vector in transacation, i.e. get vector, update, set vector.

I write some simple labda, but stuck with that code wont compiles.

```
    auto transaction  = [&key](firebase::database::MutableData* data){
    auto value = data->GetValue();
    if(!value.is_vector() or value.is_null())
        return firebase::database::kTransactionResultAbort;
    std::vector<firebase::Variant> taskList = value.vector();
    //!!    taskList.push_back(firebase::Variant(key)); !!//
    data->SetValue(firebase::Variant(taskList));
    return firebase::database::kTransactionResultSuccess;
};
dbref.Child("/users/" +userId+ "/tasks/").RunTransaction(transaction);
```

I wonna to add param to that labda. Can I do it in another way?

Compiller errors:

```
    tasksmanager.cpp:62:72: error: no matching function for call to 'firebase::database::DatabaseReference::RunTransaction(TasksManager::createTask(Task*)::<lambda(firebase::database::MutableData*)>&)'
     dbref.Child("/users/" +userId+ "/tasks/" + key).RunTransaction(tran);
                                                                        ^
tasksmanager.cpp:62:72: note: candidate is:
In file included from ..\firebase_cpp_sdk\include/firebase/database.h:9:0,
                 from tasksmanager.cpp:2:
..\firebase_cpp_sdk\include/firebase/database/database_reference.h:178:24: note: firebase::Future<firebase::database::DataSnapshot> firebase::database::DatabaseReference::RunTransaction(firebase::database::TransactionResult (*)(firebase::database::MutableData*), bool)
   Future<DataSnapshot> RunTransaction(DoTransaction* transaction_function,
                        ^
..\firebase_cpp_sdk\include/firebase/database/database_reference.h:178:24: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'TasksManager::createTask(Task*)::<lambda(firebase::database::MutableData*)>' to 'firebase::database::TransactionResult (*)(firebase::database::MutableData*)'
```

Answer (score 0):

After my research for this problem I can give an answer;
For that workflow we can use `std::function` class from c++11 (or never);

```
std::function<firebase::database::DoTransaction> callback;
callback = [any captures here](firebase::database::MutableData* mutableData) { ..yours code here... };
databaseReference.RunTransaction(callback.target<firebase::database::DoTransaction>());
```